# How to getElementsByTagName in a for loop

Tags: javascript

I try to this. but could not success. please help.

```js
var myP = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = 0; i < myP.lenght; myP++) {
  myP[i].style.color = red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <p>first paragraph </p>
  <p>2nd paragraph </p>
  <p>3rd paragraph </p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's just a typo: `lenght` instead of `length`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder think that might be the edit and not his actual code.

Comment: @H77: It's in [the first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8c411268-c591-4a1b-a536-27d7bda7bd5d/view-source), and sadly we see this exact typo posted as a question **a lot**.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder strange.. all i see in the first revision is `var myP = document.getElementsByTagName('p'); for (var i = 0; i`.

Comment: @H77: That's because there's a `<script>` element and you're looking at the rendered result. I updated the link above to the source link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems with the code. First: `myP.lenght` should be `myP.length`. Second: You are incrementing `myP`, you should increment `i` and the third: `style.color` should be `"red"` and not `red`.

```js
var myP = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = 0; i < myP.length; i++) { // should be i++
  myP[i].style.color = "red"; // color = "red"
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <p>first paragraph </p>
  <p>2nd paragraph </p>
  <p>3rd paragraph </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myP = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = 0; i < myP.length; i++) { // <-- increment i, not myP
  myP[i].style.color = 'red'; // <-- string not variable
}
```